# Entity reference and associated data

Tags: entities

Assuming I have two distinct entities A and B, with B having an Entity Reference field to A, how can I associate other data (=other fields) with the Entity Reference?

For example, assume that A is "Political parties" and B "Politicians", and I'd like to store a date range field for the politician's membership in said party.

Comment: I dont want to design your data for you, but it almost sounds like you need an interim entity to store this. Maybe a few. I am not sure if fieldable relationships are a thing, yet.

Comment: You can't, by database design an entity reference can only store two values: the target type (node, taxonomy term,...) and the numeric id of the target. You can either nest the reference inside an additional entity (e.g. a [Paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) with the ER field and your additional data), or code your own field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a paragraph type (paragraph module replaces field collection in Drupal 8) which contains a reference to your entity type A and a (or more) date and in your entity type B, have a reference to this paragraph.

You can also create a custom field which contains a reference to your entity type A and a date if you want have particular behavior (for example, don't allow users to sort items and sort them automatically by date).